# Keymapping problem when working with Emacs and Openbox

Tags: emacs, openbox, xmodmap

I have an Apple keyboard and I had to do some remapping of the keys to make the `mod-4` key the first key to the left of the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar for when working with Emacs.  The below script worked fine when I was using the dwm window manager, but after switching to Openbox I have found that instead of swapping keycodes between the option and command keys, both of the keys are doing the same thing.

One odd thing I noticed, was on the new setup when I click run `showkey` and press the option and command keys I get 56 and 125 respectively, but these keys don't work at all when inserting them into the below script instead of the 64 and 133.

I must admit I created the script below by continually tweaking it until it worked so there could be a much better way of doing it.

#### .xmodmap

```
# switch alt and command...the switch is not being done properly
xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = Alt_L"
xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Meta_L"

# remap of mod 4
xmodmap -e "clear Mod4"
xmodmap -e "add Mod4 = Super_L"
```

## Update

I got used to the previous keyboard setup and gave up trying to tweak it.  Unfortunately, after a recent restart the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> no longer worked so here I am again.

This time instead of the mapping used above I ran `xmodmap -pke > ~/.xmod` and tweaked the keys there instead (which is much easier).

However, things are still not quite right.  The <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> still functions as normal except when the `xev` command is run, then it returns the following which does seem to show the correct mapping:

```
# caplock
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
root 0x156, subw 0x0, time 4858000, (57,-31), root:(426,402),
state 0x2, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

# ctrl-L
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
root 0x156, subw 0x0, time 4805947, (686,148), root:(1055,581),
state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

# Alt-L
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
root 0x156, subw 0x0, time 4555825, (-158,-649), root:(959,133),
state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

# Super-L
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
root 0x156, subw 0x0, time 4920564, (-63,169), root:(306,602),
state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: On PCs (I don't know if this is also true on Macs) `showkey` doesn't show the same keycodes that X uses. Run `xev` to see the X keycodes and their actions. Show us the output of `xmodmap -pm` and the output of `xev` when you press each of the keys involved.

Comment: I added an update above for the xmodmap -pm command

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apple_Keyboard and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard. To summarize, you can tell the keyboard driver in the kernel to behave differently, rather than hacking things in X.

Comment: If it was working in DWM my guess is that a conflict with `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` is the issue.

Comment: Have you considered using udev to remap keys instead of xmodmap? udev would just require a hwdb file to remap the scancodes to specific keycodes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to place the following at the beginning of your `~/.xmod`

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
remove Mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L
remove Mod4 = Super_L Hyper_L
```

And the following at the bottom of `~/.xmod`

```
add Control = Control_L
add Mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L
add Mod4 = Super_L Hyper_L
```

This will update the system to recognize the modifier nature of these keys.